# Ember.js how to create an Array that I can index

Tags: arrays, ember.js, controllers, indices

I'm having trouble indexing an array.  From looking around I found some examples of how to index items in a controller through a view http://jsfiddle.net/WSwna/14/

My application gets the data from a REST call as follows

```
Videos.Store = DS.Store.extend({
revision: 12,
url: "http://localhost/",
adapter: Videos.Adapter
})
```

My router is as follows

```
Videos.Router.map(function(){
this.resource('videos', {path: '/'});
this.route('forms');
})

Videos.VideosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return Videos.Video.find();
    }
});
```

And when I implement the HTML as

```
{{#each controller}}
.....
{{/each}}
```

My data displays.

However I want to implement the example from the link http://jsfiddle.net/WSwna/14/
But I have a problem with generating a Videos.VideosController and passing that to the {{#each iterator}}

My Videos.VideosController looks like this

```
    Videos.VideosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    model: function(){
        return Videos.Video.find();
    }
});


Videos.VideoView = Ember.View.extend({
    content: null,
    adjustedIndex: function(){
        return this.getPath('_parentView.contentIndex') + 1;
    }.property()
});
```

But when I use that in the HTML as follows:

```
{{#each Videos.VideosController }}
```

I receive an error telling me that content must implement Ember.Array. You passed Videos.VideosController.  As I understand it Ember provided a default array collection to be iterated over but now that I wish to extend this controller I am having difficulty creating an array of the data to pass to the view.  I'm also unclear how the View code hooks into this extended controller.

Any ideas that can help clarify this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> However I want to implement the example from the link http://jsfiddle.net/WSwna/14/ But I have a problem with generating a Videos.VideosController and passing that to the {{#each iterator}}

Altough it's not the recomended way, but to achieve what you are trying to do with your `VideosController` you should create an instance rather then extending. This would look something like this:

```
Videos.videosController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: [{ name: 'Goodfellas' }, { name: 'The Aviator' }, { name: 'The Departed' }]
});
```

then you can use it like this to iterate over:

```
{{#each Videos.videosController}}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

Two things to note here, we are not extending the `ArrayController` but instead creating directly an instance of it, and we are also using lower case `videosController` to point out that it's an instance.

One more thing worth mentioning is that a `controller` does not have a `model` hook like a `route` has.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

After your last comment I realized what you really wanted to do, so I've put together a small jsbin showing how you could use the data from your model to feed your `Videos.videosController`'s content, have a look [here](http://jsbin.com/udecik/3/edit).

But basically what you have to do is to hook into the `afterModel` hook of your `route` and pass the already retrieved model to your `Videos.videosController`'s content:

```
Videos.videosController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: []
});

Videos.VideosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Videos.Video.find();
  },
  afterModel: function(model) {
    Videos.videoController.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a great help.  But I'm still stuck. One of the things I'm really struggling with is that when the route creates the Array from the model how can I use it?  So in your example above you have hardcoded content: [{name: 'Goodfellas'}, {name: 'foobar'}]  but I want to be able to do something like Videos.Video.find().

Comment: @LindaKeating, I've edited my answer, I think now it's reflecting more your use case, hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks so much.  It's beginning to make a bit more sense to me. I'm still stuck though.  I've searched the API for documentation about 'afterModel' and can't find any.  Also the code runs for me without producing errors but I don't think the array in videosController is being populated with data.  When I debug through it somewhere along the line I get an error of Expected hash or Mixin instance, got [object Object] ember.  May have to give up! but thanks again

Comment: @LindaKeating, well yes, the new router additions are not really well documented, but you can find here https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945 more info on `beforeModel`, `afterModel` etc.